# Querying with many (~100) search terms with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I need to do a query on my database that might be something like this where there could realistically be 100 or more search terms.

```
public IQueryable<Address> GetAddressesWithTown(string[] towns)
{
    IQueryable<Address> addressQuery = DbContext.Addresses;
    addressQuery.Where( x => towns.Any( y=> x.Town == y ) );
    return addressQuery;
}
```

However when it contains more than about 15 terms it throws and exception on execution because the SQL generated is too long.

Can this kind of query be done through `Entity Framework`?

What other options are there available to complete a query like this?

Comment: You can use a Store Procedure mapped inside your Entity Data model.

Comment: You could use a Stored Procedure or perhaps a search engine on the side.

Comment: What does "fall over" mean? Too slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, are we talking about THIS EXACT SQL?

In that case it is a very simple "open your eyes thing".

There is a way (contains) to map that string into an IN Clause, that results in ONE sql condition (town in ('','',''))

Let me see whether I get this right:

> addressQuery.Where( x => towns.Any( y=> x.Town == y ) );

should be

> addressQuery.Where ( x => towns.Contains (x.Town)

The resulting SQL will be a LOT smaller. 100 items is still taxing it - I would dare saying you may have a db or app design issue here and that requires a business side analysis, I have not me this requirement in 20 years I work with databases.

Comment: +1 This definitely helps; the generated sql still isn't very good, but it's much, much better than before; and it's also a very simple change.

Comment: Imagine a situation where you have a list of devices and you want to deliver content to those devices.  The client asks for specific towns where they have stores and want to target those towns.  Nationwide they might have 300 stores hence you want all devices that are located in the towns with stores.

Comment: ...or really any aggregate set query in which one of the sets isn't already in the database.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this solution can heavily pollute the query plan cache of your server, which may matter as queries grow more complex.

Comment: @Neil No client will have this "on demand". Stuff like this sort of grouping is often done in an editor (and then kept in the database). You are better off, strategically, to find a structure where you can use a database side join instead of injecting the list of towns into the SQL, especially when it gets larger.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne Yes, correct. Let's bother about a little query plan pollution instead of using nice SQL with a decent performance. Query plan pollution is normally not THAT much a problem. On top, it is not lke the SQL Server team is full of idiots - they are quite nice in optimizing that. I call you on premature optimization.

Comment: @TomTom: In my experience, you'll need bulk-insert or TVPs sometime anyway, and if you have the conding-infrastructure for that in place, it's the most appropriate solution to this problem; precisely because it allows a database-side join rather than injecting a list of towns into the sql.  In any case, I'm not suggesting that this solution is bad - I think it's a *good* solution.  I just don't think that your out-of-hand dismissal of TVP's or bulk insert makes any sense.

Comment: On the topic of premature optimization: of *course* it's premature optimization in an application that consists solely of this one query in which no more than 100 towns can be passed.  Whether that's the case in any particular application will depend on the specifics.  Having encountered exactly this problem in practice I can assure you it's not theoretical.  (Also, you seem to suggest that queries necessarily cannot share the same query plan if they are to be "nice SQL with a decent performance": but that's not the case).

Comment: I'll give this a try on Monday, thanks.  Would this kind of thing be better being done on a NoSql database on a map reduce or something like that?  I can utilize couchbase if I want and cache all the addresses and then perform queries on the cache

Comment: Thanks, this has got the query working and running a heck of a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scenario where you'd want to use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) as this will help you create an *Or* based predicate and construct your dynamic lambda expression.

This is part of a library called LinqKit by Joseph Albahari who created LinqPad.

```
 public IQueryable<Address> GetAddressesWithTown(string[] towns)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Address>();

  foreach (string town in towns)
  {
    string temp = town;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Town.Equals(temp));
  }

  return DbContext.Addresses.Where (predicate);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this will help - the generated SQL will still be huge.

Comment: It might change from `EXISTS` joins to a simple `WHERE` predicate. That would help a lot.

Comment: Why would that help a lot?  You still have a parameter per value in the string-array...

Comment: @EamonNerbonne you can have about 1000 T-SQL parameters per batch. That gets him very far. Not so sure about 1000 joins...

Comment: A yes, I see what you mean - I hadn't expected the any clause to be implemented via a join; that's indeed rather extreme.

Answer (score 0):

You've broadly got two options:

- You can replace `.Any` with a `.Contains` alternative.
- You can use plain SQL with table-valued-parameters.

Using `.Contains` is easier to implement and will help performance because it translated to an inline sql `IN` clause; so 100 towns shouldn't be a problem.  However, it also means that the exact sql depends on the exact number of towns: you're forcing sql-server to recompile the query for each number of towns.  These recompilations can be expensive when the query is complex; and they can evict other query plans from the cache as well.

Using table-valued-parameters is the more general solution, but it's more work to implement, particularly because it means you'll need to write the SQL query yourself and cannot rely on the entity framework.  (Using `ObjectContext.Translate` you can still unpack the query results into strongly-typed objects, despite writing sql).  Unfortunately, you cannot use the entity framework yet to pass a lot of data to sql server efficiently.  The entity framework doesn't support table-valued-parameters, nor temporary tables (it's a [commonly requested feature](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015347-table-valued-parameters), however).

A bit of TVP sql would look like this `select ... from ... join @townTableArg townArg on townArg.town = address.town` or `select ... from ... where address.town in (select town from @townTableArg)`.

You probably *can* work around the EF restriction, but it's not going to be fast and will probably be tricky.  A workaround would be to insert your values into some intermediate table, then join with that - that's still 100 inserts, but those are separate statements.  If a future version of EF supports [batch CUD statements](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015357-batch-cud-support), this might actually work reasonably.

Almost equivalent to table-valued paramters would be to bulk-insert into a temporary table and join with that in your query.  Mostly that just means you're table name will start with '#' rather than '@' :-).  The temp table has a little more overhead, but you can put indexes on it and in *some* cases that means the subsequent query will be much faster (for really huge data-quantities).

Unfortunately, using either temporary tables or bulk insert from C# is a hassle.  The simplest solution here is to make a `DataTable`; this can be passed to either.  However, datatables are relatively slow; the over might be relevant once you start adding millions of rows. The fastest (general) solution is to implement a custom `IDataReader`, almost as fast is an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`.

By the way, to use a table-valued-parameter, the shape ("type") of the table parameter needs to be declared on the server; if you use a temporary table you'll need to create it too.

Some pointers to get you started:

- http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/
- [SqlBulkCopy from a List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913371/sqlbulkcopy-from-a-list)

Comment: -1. He is not using entity framework to pass a lot of data to start with. Funnny how everyone throws archtiectural advice around and totally ignores that the particular LINQ statement is not what you should touch in SQL for a simple IN clause.

Comment: I'm surprised you think so; but to each there own.  It's not a matter of architecture, it's just that the SQL IN statement applied to explicit scalar parameters is a poor match for a variable-sized set.  Unfortunately, the alternatives sql server provides aren't supported by the entity framework.

Comment: @TomTom: could you explain "the particular LINQ statement is not what you should touch in SQL for a simple IN clause" - I don't understand how this related to my answer.

Comment: are you joking? His example is "find where town is one of a list of 100". Any sensible person would use an IN statement in SQL (town IN [list of towns]) instead of 100 "town like x" statements. THIS is his problem, as per example and I was right as per his comment on my answer.

Comment: Of course - but the question is whether you do `IN (...variable-length-param-list...)` or `IN (select * from @tablevar)` - and the latter is much faster, and allows for more input, and is designed for precisely that purpose.  Your suggestion to use 100 "town like x" statements has nothing to do with this answer.  If you want these kind of set queries commonly then I stand by the TVP or bulk-insert approaches; these are the only solutions that really work well.