# sqlbulkcopy from a ConcurrentDictionary<int, Guid>

Tags: c#, fastmember

I have a ConcurrentDictionary and I am trying to make use of fastmember as per this example by [marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913371/sqlbulkcopy-from-a-list) but what I have is just an array of Guid not a complex type with properties.

So when i use

```
var pastTripsToDelete = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Guid>();
var uniqueTripID = Guid.NewGuid();
pastTripsToDelete.AddOrUpdate(1, uniqueTripID, (key, oldValue) => uniqueTripID);

using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(pastTripsToDelete.Values))
{
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable";
    bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
}
```

I receive "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values", I guess it is looking for properties to map it to the columns in the table but I do not have any as it is a simple array of Guids.

Comment: don't guess see on call stack on which line this is happening.

Comment: It is happening on bcp.WriteToServer(reader) and stack trace shows it on  FastMember_dynamic.Guid_1.get_Item(Object , String ). the actual message is Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: name