# How to get a normal SQL table with columns from a SPLIT_STRING table

Tags: .net, sql-server

My task is to get an array of objects (the data) from .NET to an ordinary table in SQL Server and I'm not sure entirely how. Each object in the array looks something like this:

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "firstName": "Test",
   "lastName": "User",
   "dob": "20-10-2000"
}
```

and I need to get it into something like this:

| Id | FirstName | LastName | DOB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | User | 20-10-2000 |

What I've tried so far (since I haven't reached the end, the number is the order):

1. Stringify the object via `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and pass it to the stored procedure.
2. Change the separators in the string to remove "[{" (beginning of array), "}]" (end of array) and make sure the objects are separated with "|". Example: `[{person1},{ person2}]` -> `person1|person2`
3. Split the resulting string at "|" with STRING_SPLIT so I get each person on a different row.

This is the result of (3):
[image: string_split result]

This is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"ID":"1234567890123","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Tester","SecondName":"AVACUM","BirthDate":"1950-04-11T00:00:00","CPAS":"12345678901","PensionType":1,"SurvivorshipType":0,"StartDate":"2010-04-11T00:00:00"}]'

DECLARE @replacedSeparator NVARCHAR(max)
SET @replacedSeparator = REPLACE(@json, '},{', '|');

-- replace beginning of stringified array
SET @replacedSeparator = REPLACE(@replacedSeparator, '[{', '');

-- replace end of stringified array
SET @replacedSeparator = REPLACE(@replacedSeparator, '}]', '');

-- primary split of stringified array to get all persons
DECLARE @splitString TABLE (value NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @splitString (value)
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@replacedSeparator, '|');

SELECT value FROM @splitString
```

Any ideas? I thought about splitting each person into a new table or something that would contain the data of a single person and each row would have the format `"property":"value"` but I don't see the point in that.

Comment: That's JSON, not comma-separated values. Why not use [OPENJSON or any of the JSON functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) to extract what you want? Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: BTW that `dob` violates the [standard way of representing dates in JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#page-5), the ISO8601 format. The `BirthDate` in the screenshot on the other hand is a valid ISO8601 date. Post the table schema and a sample of the actual data in the question *as text*, so people can create answers that show how to correctly parse the actual data

Comment: `an array of objects (the data) from .NET to an ordinary table in SQL Server` is the real question how to save objects to a table? That doesn't need any kind of parsing. All you need is to repeat the same INSERT command using a SqlCommand with different parameter values. If you use an ORM like EF Core, the ORM will generate the commands.  Post the *actual* data and code.

Comment: If you're only looking to insert data then [this answer might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981179/1048425). You can create a reader from your array, and use `SqlBulkCopy` to add that to a table with minimal effort

Comment: Why not OPENJSON() : `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (ID nvarchar(20) '$.ID', FirstName nvarchar(100) '$.FirstName', LastName nvarchar(100) '$.LastName', BirthDate nvarchar(19) '$.BirthDate')`?

Comment: Agreed, SqlBulkCopy is the way to go for a straight insert. Otherwise use a TVP or JSON

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `OPENJSON` in sql server to read from a JSON document and load data into SQL Server but its best to do this sort of data manipulation in .Net layer. SQL Server is really good dealing with rows and columns but the performance when dealing with XML or JSON is appalling. After all SQL Server was not designed to deal with documents.

My suggestion would be to do the JSON shredding in your .net layer, get the data in a table format and then pass the data to a proc in SQL Server. A proc that accepts a table valued parameter, to learn more about what a table valued parameter is, have a read of this [How to use Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This will take place 1 time per day at most, at night, when nobody uses the system. So performance is not a concern. I just tested Option 2 from [Parse Json in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) (works fine) and for 306 objects in the array it took less than a second, basically instant. Even if it takes 2-3 minutes for the whole list, as I said, performance is not that big of a concern. This is automated and will be executed at night.